# How to add a column in an existing AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I need to add several columns to the dbo.AspNetUsers. This has been created using the "Individual Accounts" option. I have tried what I have searched on the internet but I can't get it to work.

In the generated ApplicationDbContext I modified it to be like so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I ran the add-migration but I just got an empty Migration file.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace BlazorApp4.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class ModifiedUserDatabase : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But I still tried the update-database but nothing has been added to the table that I needed.

I think I need to place it in the ApplicationUser that inherits IdentityUser. But I don't see it anywhere in my blazor application.

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Is this the actual code, ie you have added properties to the DbContext ? Show us the `ApplicationUser` class.

Comment: @Henk Hollerman That's the thing. If you will look at the image. I don't see any ApplicationUser. But in the searches I made on the net, i am supposed to place the new properties on that ApplicationUser class.

Comment: I can see an ApplicationUser.cs file there. Look closer. VS also has a searchbox in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

- add the properties to the ApplicationUser class.
- make sure that class inherits from `IdentityUser`
- find all other occurences of `IdentityUser` in your .cs and .razor files and replace with `ApplicationUser`.
- inherit the context with the new class as Type argument:
   `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`
- when you override OnModelCreating, don't forget to call
  `base.OnModelCreating(builder);`
- now you can add-migrate